# Symfony form POST handling

Tags: php, symfony

How does Symfony handle POST method towards controllers? For example, this code in ASP.NET makes it possible to use an exact similar name for a controller, in a different manner:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

 // POST: Objects/Create
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public ActionResult Create()
 {
     //Code here that only runs on POST method of a form
     return View();
 }
```

I have seen something like:

```
public function createAction()
{
    return $this->render('formPage.html.twig');
}

/**
* @Method({"POST"})
*/
public function createAction()
{
    //Some code...

    return new Response('Added item with id: ' . $item->getId() . 'to database');
}
```

Is the latter possible and similar to the former? Is it necessary to use such annotation like this or can it also be added to routing and if so, should I make different routing names or something?

```
movie_create:
    path:     /movies/create
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Movie:create }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controllers in Symfony2 are classes, in which you cannot re-defined methods with the same name.

I'm afraid you'll need to either split your controller into two:

```
class ViewController extends Controller {

    public function createAction()
    {
        return $this->render('formPage.html.twig');
    }
}

class CreateController extends Controller {

    /**
    * @Method({"POST"})
    */
    public function createAction()
    {
        //Some code...

        return new Response('Added item with id: ' . $item->getId() . 'to database');
    }
}
```

Or a much simpler solution, simply re-name your methods in your routing:

```
movie_view:
    path:     /movies/view
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Movie:view }
movie_create:
    path:     /movies/create
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Movie:create }
    requirements:
        _method: POST
```

Comment: After reading these answers I was thinking about your second solution. Thanks!

Comment: You can also keep it on one controller per resource. Just with different action names and different request methods allowed.

Answer (score 2):

You can define what methods a route will accept, either by annotation as per your example or in the *routing.yml*;

```
my_route:
    path:     /foo/bar/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Fubar:foo }
    methods:  [POST]
```

this will acept only POST.

You can't define two methods with the same name, that is a limitation of PHP in general.  In your case you could have one route to show the form and another to handle the request.

Comment: You can actually define two methods with the same name in PHP, but they need to be in different scopes to avoid collision.